# How to compare only date of dateTime while filtering from mongo in c#?

Tags: c#, mongodb, asp.net-core, mongodb-.net-driver

My date time property defined in my model class named `Recommendation` is

```
public DateTime? DueDate { get; set; }
```

I am trying to filter and retrieve data from mongo where the field `DueDate` matches the current date only not including time.

I made a filter expression for querying on mongo.

```
var dateFilter = Builders<Recommendation>.Filter.Eq(x => x.DueDate, DateTime.Now)
```

`DateTime.Now` also returns the date with a timestamp.

Also in mongo, the `DueDate` field value is `2022-12-08T05:00:00.000+00:00`

How can I modify the filter query above to filter and fetch records from mongo based on date only and not timestamp?

Answer (score 2):

You could convert them to strings:

```cs
var dateFilter = Builders<Recommendation>.Filter.Eq(x => x.DueDate.ToString("yyyyMMdd"), DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd");
```

No promises on the performance of this.

Comment: When applying on x.DueDate.ToString("yyyyMMdd") it is giving error that "No overload for method ToString takes 1 argument". Also, DueDate is nullable as well -DateTime? .
It is working fine on DateTime.Now though but only gives an error on DueDate. It's only accepting ToString() without arguments on DueDate part

Comment: If they are Nullable, it might be: `x.DueDate.GetValueOrDefault().ToString("yyyyMMdd")`